# How to properly decompile/recompile android APK file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, android, decompile

How to properly decompile and recompile android APK file on Ubuntu, preferably with the minimum tools required, just for this purpose. I need recompile electronic book.

Comment: no idea but if you mean to run an android thing on something non android, then how about an android emulator , genymotion (don't know if there is one for linux), or this one may be windows only  http://www.amiduos.com/  but you could run a windows vm and then the android emulator in that.